# webpack json-loader fails in lernajs controlled dependencies

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I'm using [lernajs](http://lernajs.io) to manage a monorepo. There, I have two packages:

1. *app* (via create-react-app)
2. *lib* (a react component transpiled with `babel-cli`)

When adding `require('./package.json')` to *app*, webpack compiles as expected. The json file is loaded as expected. However, when I put `require('./package.json')` into the *lib* package, webpack fails with `Module not found: 'json'`. The json loader is working fine for dependencies *not* controlled by lernajs.

The issue persists if *lib* is requiring another library (e.g. cheerio) that imports a json file. Same as above, if cheerio is included in *app* instead, it works fine.

If you don't know lernajs, it's a tool to manage monorepos and it's basically symlinking the *lib* package into `./app/node_modules/`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by adding `json-loader` to the project's root directory package.json!